# My app cannot generate device token

Tags: swift2, apple-push-notifications

Suddenly my app cannot generate device token.
I created a app to receive remote push notification, thje app worked well, but today my app dont generate device token, I run code on xcode and dont generate token. No delegates method called.
I dont change anything and dont work more. The function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken dont work. Look:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print(deviceToken)
}
```

dont print nothing

this function do nothing:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let types:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]


    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: [newsCategory]))

    return true
}
```

Why this problem? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have also to call `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` after registering the settings.